# Force a file to open when a solution file (.sln) is opened

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, solution, readme

I know that Visual Studio stores and persists opened files in the `*.user` files that it generates, but these files are not supposed to be checked in to TFS or shared between a team.

We have `README.md` files that are "solution items" in a lot of our solutions in TFS. What I want is, when a solution is opened, have the `README.md` file open if it is not open already. (Sort of mimicking how GitHub shows you the readme file when you browse to the project homepage, but this is strictly TFS and Visual Studio.) Documentation is huge for us, so we want to forcibly display it to anyone who opens a solution, making it hard to miss.

Is this possible with any sort of configuration line in the `.sln` file, or an XML entry in a `.csproj` file, or possibly an extension? I would like this to be something that can persist between different workstations using TFS (unless it's just an extension, in which case we can all install that).

Comment: There isn't any built in support for this. Paul's advice of an extension might be the best. Might not be a terrible thing to suggest on the Visual Studio uservoice either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the [Open a file from the solution directory on opening a solution](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#OnSolutionOpened) extension for Visual Commander to open README.md.