# How to auto run a dotnet command when opening a solution in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am interested to run dotnet watch test when opening a solution with my unit tests in visual studio 2017. Is there a way to run that just after the solution is open without doing it manually?

Comment: Open the solution in cmd or powershell, and run the test from there?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229249/force-a-file-to-open-when-a-solution-file-sln-is-opened

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio Task Runner can run any arbitrary CMD command when a project/solution is opened.

Prerequisites: [Command Task Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommandTaskRunner) extention.

1. Add `Foo.cmd` with a target command to your project having `dotnet watch` package installed. It could have one line of code:

   ```
   dotnet watch run
   ```

Make sure the file is properly encoded to UTF-8 without BOM.

2. After `Command Task Runner` extention install, `Add to Task Runner` option should be accessible from context menu of `*.cmd` files. Press it and choose per-project level. As a result, `commands.json` should appear in the project.
3. Go to VS `View -> Other Windows -> Task Runner Explorer`. Set up the binding for the `Foo` command in the context menu: `Bindings -> Project Open` (the window refresh could help to see a recently added command).
4. Re-open the solution and check a command execution result in `Task Runner Explorer`.

How it could look:

[image]

[image]