# How to make VS 2017 run some custom code after any project is loaded?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Every project in our solution includes a custom targets file, so at first I hooked up to run after the Compile target in the design time build. But, VS does not call it always. So, the relevant script is not always called - not good.

Is there another way? If you suggest VS extension, please provide more details. I know about the VS extensions, but have never written any. Maybe there is an easier way?

**EDIT 1**

In the end the Command Task Runner extension does not satisfy all the scenarios. It does not run:

- until its Tool Windows is activated for the first time
- when a project is unloaded and then reloaded

So, I need a custom VS extension or another solution.

Comment: All VS project files (vcxproj, csproj, you didn't specify) are in essence MSBuild xml files. There are advanced features of [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild) that you can use, but have to edit the file manually. Look for tasks.

Comment: @Dialecticus - what tasks do you suggest me to lookup that run after any project is **loaded** (not built, mind you) ?

Comment: Ah. Probably can't be done in MSBuild, because you have to run MSBuild, and then it's already late. But you said you tried to run something after the Compile target, which is also late, so I'm confused now.

Comment: @Dialecticus - Visual Studio sometimes runs design time build - it is a special build that runs in the background and only for a number of targets. But VS does not do this design time build always. Google Visual Studio design time build for more details.

Comment: After some search I found possible solutions, but you will have to check them out yourself. One includes [a custom Nuget package](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ea5143db-a775-4919-9918-a784e9b70b19/how-to-execute-scripts-when-opening-a-solution-file?forum=vsx), and the other [an extension from markteplace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44127882).

Comment: Custom NuGet package does not work.It might have worked in the past, but now it does not. Extension could be a better.

Comment: @Dialecticus - Actually, the extension turned out to work for me. Please, arrange it as an answer. I will accept.

Comment: The (very detailed) answer already exists, albeit for another question. Maybe we should close this one as a duplicate? And upvote the originals..

Comment: @Dialecticus - please, see **EDIT 1**.